# Using awk to concatenate files and add a part of the filename as a field

Tags: unix, awk

I have a set of CSV files that are named like

```
ASSET_20160101.csv,...,ASSET_20161031.csv
```

i.e. `ASSET_{date}.csv`

I would like to concatenate two columns (say, cusip and return) in one `csv` and add the date as a third column. The two relevant fields are in fixed places, in columns 1 and 16. The date is not a column in the files and it exists only in the file name.

I got as far as:

```
awk -F',' '{printf("%5s,%5s,%3.5f\n", FILENAME,$1,$16}' ASSET_* > output.csv
```

But this is not what I want, as it print the entire file name as a column.

Comment: Provide sample data from the `csv` files and let us know what is your expected output. This information is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about wrapping `FILENAME` in the `substr` function?

`awk -F',' '{printf("%5s,%5s,%3.5f\n", substr(FILENAME,7,8),$1,$16}' ASSET_* > output.csv`